# PHP array Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Tags: php, arrays, soap, parameters

I got the following parameters as a response from SOAP client.The parameter Serial Equipment are displaying first values and then giving error as Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string. I have many values which comes under Serial Equipment parameter and its an array. So dont know how to display all the values

Code:

```
function getVehicleValuation()
{

    $client = new SoapClient($wsdl, $options);
    $result = $client->getVehicleValuation($params);    
    $return = array(

                                'Serial Equipment' => $result->vehicle->SerialEquipment

                                );
    return $return; 
}
```

Trying to display result from this code:

```
  if($parameter['aktion'] == 'getVehicle') 
    { 
    ob_start();
    var_dump(Login());
    $s = ob_get_clean();
     $returned_array=getVehicleValuation();
    foreach($returned_array as $objects) 
    {
        foreach($objects as $key => $obj) 
        {       
        echo "key.: " . $key . "<br>";
        echo $obj->Code . "<br>";
        echo $obj->Desc_Short . "<br>";
        echo $obj->Desc_Long . "<br>";
        echo $obj->Esaco . "<br>";
        } 
    }  

}
```

When i use simply var_dump(SerialEquipment) the ouput will give result as :

```
array (size=1) 

    'Serial Equipment' => 
        array (size=41)
          0 => 
            object(stdClass)[6]
              public 'Code' => int 204093
              public 'Desc_Short' => string 'Ablagefach mittig in GepÃ¤ckraumtrennwand;ESACO_UG(122)' (length=55)
              public 'Desc_Long' => string 'Ablagefach mittig in GepÃ¤ckraumtrennwand inkl. verschiebbarem Haltenetz' (length=72)
              public 'Esaco' => 
                object(stdClass)[7]
                  ...
          1 => 
            object(stdClass)[8]
              public 'Code' => int 160452
              public 'Desc_Short' => string 'Airbag fÃ¼r Fahrer und Beifahrer, 2-stufi;ESACO_UG(103)' (length=55)
              public 'Desc_Long' => string 'Airbag fÃ¼r Fahrer und Beifahrer 2-stufig' (length=41)
              public 'Esaco' => 
                array (size=2)
                  ...
          2 => 
            object(stdClass)[11]
              public 'Code' => int 195607
              public 'Desc_Short' => string 'Airbag: Kopf- u. Seiten - Airbags vorn;ESACO_UG(104,102)' (length=56)
              public 'Desc_Long' => string 'Airbag: Seitenairbag fÃ¼r Fahrer und Beifahrer (Kopf/Thorax)' (length=60)
              public 'Esaco' => 
                array (size=2)
                  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If $result->vehicle->SerialEquipment return an array, you should probably USE that array to fill in the value for your key 'Serial Equipment'.

Try a print_r($result->vehicle->SerialEquipment); in your php code to investigate the content.

Now it is up to you what you want to do with it. Do you want to transfer the complete content of that array into your key 'Serial Equipment'? Or just a few values?

If you want the WHOLE structure (whatever it is) that comes from $result->vehicle->SerialEquipment packaged into a string, have a look at JSON.
Json can translate the array into a string, which you can assign.

You pack it before assigning to your key 'Serial Equipment', so it contains a string.
Then unpack it on receiving.

Have a look here:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

and

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: i am sorry i want to display the complete aray result of Serial Equipment as this is very important parameter for me. And i did not used Json Encode Decode so dont know how to use it. Can you tell me in my example ?

Answer (score 0):

As the returned value is an array, you have to loop on its items.
Try something like

```
foreach($returned_array as $key => $val) {
    if (is_array($val)) {
        echo $key . ' => ' . "<br/>";
        foreach($val as $k => $v) {
            echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;' . $k . ' ' . $v . '<br/>';
        }
    }
    else {
        echo $key . ' ' . $val . '<br/>';
    }
}
```

This is a code sample, it is possible to extend it and code a recursive function that will display a more complex structure like this one : http://dev.armage.org/wiki/doku.php?id=web:php:debug

Comment: i tried to use your loop it works fine if i dont use Serial Equipment in my code but when i used it gives an error as Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in /www/1/html/webservices/schwackeNet/index.php on line where we wrote echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;' . $k . ' ' . $v . '<br/>';

Comment: That means some $v are object and you have to process it specifically. It's an example of "the more complex structure" I cited above :) You may try the debug function I linked, which should help you in this case.

Comment: I am sorry i have seen your complex structure and it looks very complex to me ;) did not understood. Can you please point where i can make changes for this..Its just a small change required to display this array

Comment: Please check the updated question i have shown my output results of SerialEquipment

Comment: Sorry, I have to go, but if you want to try my function, put it on your code and try debug($returned_array).